# i want to loop this program from the start again when the input is yes in python

Tags: python

> some use is inputting bids on an item and they have a specific buyer number.i can only loop it for bidding on one item.please help me how could i start the program again by asking user in the end if he want to look for another item.

```
  item_byer=(input("enter the item number 
you want to buy:"))
k=0
for e in (bids_1):
if e==item_byer:
print("item is founded")
break
else:
 print("not founded")
k+=1
index_1=(bids_1.index(item_byer))
price=(bids_1[(index_1)+2])
description=(bids_1[(index_1)+1])
print("the price of the item 
is,",price)
bids=0
bids=price
print("if you want to enter a bid 
please enter this word,bid()")
def bid():
global bids
buyer_num=input("enter your buyer 
number!")
highest=input("enter the bid you want 
to put on this. make sure it is greater 
than previous")
a=0
while int(bids)>int(highest):
  print("bids cannot be transfered it 
should be greater than current 
 highest")
  highest=input("enter your bid again")
  a+=1
 if (bids)<(highest):
  print("bid accepted")
  highest==bids
  print("the current highest bid 
 is",highest)
  bids=highest
  else: 
    print("bid denied it should be 
  greater than the previous")
   quit
   biding=input("if you want to enter a 
   bid enter yes ")
   if biding=="yes":
    bid()
   choice=input("if you want to input 
   another item press yes")
```

Comment: Read loops, perhaps a `while True` with a break condition inside.

Comment: Annnd the indentation, Please fix it.

Comment: Where is `bids_1` defined?

Comment: Why do you have `break`  All that could have been summed to just `if item_byer in bid_1:`

Comment: And why do you have `k+=1` var when you are not even using it?

Comment: please indent your code properly

Answer (score 2):

Since there are so many things wrong with that but sticking to your originally asked question: ***how could i start the program again by asking user in the end if he want to look for another item.***

You could put your *working* code in a loop and take user input in the end, perhaps:

```
bids_1 = ['some', 'list', 'of', 'OP']

while True:
    item_ = input("enter the item number you want to buy: ")
    if item_ in bids_1:
        print("item is found")
    else:
        print("item not found")
    userInp = input("Do you want to check for another item? Press Y to continue: ")
    if userInp.upper() != 'Y':
        break
```